# SwapCursor undefined when creating a CursorLoader

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

I am receiving a "swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined" error when creating a CursorLoader. I have imported the android.support.v4 (app.LoaderManager, app.LoaderManager.Loader, Content.CursorLoader, content.Loader). Not sure what I can do to correct this issue. please advise.

loader:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;



public class LoginList extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private ListView loginList;
    private Button webLogin;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);

        loginList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
        loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        webLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);



        //Specify fileds to display in the list
        String[] from = new String[] { ListProvider.COLUMN_NAME_SITE };

        //Bind fields to listview
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.loginlist};

        // Create CursorAdapter and set it to display
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.login_listview, null, from, to);

        loginList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setEmptyText(getResources().getString(string.app_name));
    rwgisterForContextMenu(getListView());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        } */


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);


        Cursor clickedObject = (Cursor)loginList.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

        Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
        loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getsName());
        loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getwUrl());
        loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getuName());
        loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getpWord());
        loginBundle.putString("clickedNotes",((LoginDetails) clickedObject).getlNotes());

        updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

        startActivityForResult(updateDeleteLoginInfo, 0); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
        startActivity(webLoginIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int ignored, final Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor); /* swapCursor error: The method swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type SimpleCursorAdapter */


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset (Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null); /* swapCursor error: The method swapCursor(Cursor) is undefined for the type SimpleCursorAdapter */

    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you are importing `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter` and not `android.widget.CursorAdapter`

Comment: @vmironov Added import but error still exsist

Comment: What vmironov probably meant to say is to use `android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of `android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter`. Alternatively, `changeCursor` is available in all releases but has the downside of closing the old cursor (so the Loader code will probably fail)

Comment: could you format the above code, becouse it is impossible to read?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the compatibility library?

Comment: @Luksprog I have version 12 installed

Comment: @imbryk Code reformatted. Does that help you

Comment: Follow Delyans advice and use android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter instead of android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter. If you are really using the support library V12 then the error WILL go away.

Answer (score 3):

Example on how to use changeCursor() with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks instead of swapCursor().

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, DB_table.CONTENT_URI, DB_table.PROJECTION,null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

if you want to use the swapCursor() available in API 11 for older API's, remember to import the CursorAdapter from the support library.

```
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` method you initialize your adapter passing the `ListView` as the second argument.  This is incorrect, it should be the ID of a layout to instantiate for each item in the list:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to);
```

Other than that your code looks fine to me.  I've compared it against working code of mine that used a ListFragment so I don't instantiate a UI but override the `onActivityCreated(Bundle)` method.

I did take the trouble to provide a projection to cut down the amount of data extracted from database by my `ContentProvider`, but passing `null` shouldn't be a problem.

But do check that you provide the "_id" primary key column as a long in your `ContentProvier`.  To use `ListView` (and some of the other widgets) you have to have a Long based primary key, which I found really inconvenient as I already had a perfectly acceptable UUID as my primary key.